# Remote backserver with Sybase ASE

Tags: database, backup, sap-ase

I get a dump file on my local machine and I want to reload it into a remote server ASE 12.5 (from the same local machine)

I tried

> load database  from "/tmp/local.dmp"

and got

> Server 'SYBASE_BS', Procedure 'bs_read_header', Line 0: Backup Server:
>   4.26.2.1: Volume validation error: failed to obtain device information, device: "/tmp/local.dmp" error: No such file or
>   directory.  Server Message:  Number  8009, Severity  16

I guess I'm wrong because I'm trying to call (implicitly) local Backup server.
How can I set a remote server ?

Answer (score 0):

Check sybase syntax [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.commands/html/commands/commands64.htm).

You have to specify the database that you want to load.